# Как найти сумму всех результатов из цикла While?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Вопрос состоит в том, чтобы получить сумму всех результатов данного цикла. Как это сделать?

```
summa = 120
procent = 5
pribavka = 3
i = 0
a = summa - (summa / 100* procent)
print(a)
while i < 6:
    summa_next_day = summa + pribavka
    pribavka += 3
    summa_procent = summa_next_day - ((summa_next_day) / 100 * procent)
    print(summa_procent)
    i += 1
```

Comment: Замените изображения в вопросе текстом.

Comment: Нужно найти сумму `summa_procent` каждой итерации цикла?

Comment: @gil9red Именно

Comment: Создайте выше цикла переменную, например `total_sum = 0` и в цикле после `summa_procent = ` добавьте `total_sum += total_sum`. После выведите результат `print(total_sum)`

Answer (score 1):

```
summa = 120
procent = 5
pribavka = 3
i = 0
a = summa - (summa / 100* procent)
print(a)
114.0

while i < 6:
    summa_next_day = summa + pribavka
    pribavka += 3
    summa_procent = summa_next_day - ((summa_next_day) / 100 * procent)
    print(summa_procent)
    i += 1

116.85
119.7
122.55
125.4
128.25
131.1
# 116.85+119.7+122.55+125.4+128.25+131.1 = 743.85

# vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
pribavka = 3
sum([ (summa + pribavka*(it+1)) - ((summa + pribavka*(it+1)) / 100 * procent) for it in range(6)])

743.85
```

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, нужна сумма всех summa_procent? Тогда просто добавить еще одну одну переменную и в нее плюсовать результаты:

```
summa = 120
procent = 5
pribavka = 3
i = 0
a = summa - (summa / 100* procent)
# Инициализируем переменную
gross_sum = 0
print(a)
while i < 6:
    summa_next_day = summa + pribavka
    pribavka += 3
    summa_procent = summa_next_day - ((summa_next_day) / 100 * procent)
    # Прибавляем новый результат к общей сумме
    gross_sum += summa_procent
    print(summa_procent)
    i += 1
# Выводим общую сумму
print(gross_sum)
```